# How to query a result with value greater than the min(value) of a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Table A:

```
row_id     row_num
3488       1
3488       2
3488       3
4523       1
4523       2
8783       1
9999       2
9999       3
9999       4
```

How do I get a result of my table where row_num should greater than the minimum value of row_num ? [For example row_num > min(row_num)]

The expected result

```
row_id     row_num
3488       2
3488       3
4523       2
9999       3
9999       4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please post the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use min() over()

```
select row_id, row_num
from (
     select row_id, row_num, min(row_num) over() rm -- probably add partition by row_id
     from myTable
) t
where row_num > rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [ROWNUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) with Partition to partition by RowIds and then get rownum >1

```
;with cte
as
(select row_id,row_num,
row_number() over (partition by row_id order by row_num) as rownum
 from #temp
)
select row_id,row_num from cte where rownum>1
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DonaldDuck:The code itself answers,there is not much explanation to provide on this code.I will make habit of adding some explanation